# Organizando fotos do aplicativo em pasta

Tags: android, android-studio

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código para definir a descrição das fotos que meu aplicativo vai tirar e onde vão ser salvas as fotos.

```
private File criarArquivo() throws IOException {
   String descricao = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
   File pasta = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
   File imagem = new File(pasta.getPath() + File.separator + "DiabetesMonitor_" + descricao + ".jpg");
   return imagem;
}
```

Gostaria de salvar essas fotos em uma pasta com o nome do meu aplicativo na galeria de fotos do Android e não junto com as outras fotos.
O que devo fazer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raphael, encontrei esse método que cria um diretório e salva o arquivo na pasta que tu definir, nota que ele pede o **Bitmap** da imagem a ser salva e o nome do arquivo que no teu caso acredito que seria a variável `descricao`:

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/nomeDoApp");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/nomeDoApp/");
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/nomeDoApp/"), fileName);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

No teu método tu tem um objeto do tipo `File`, p/ conseguir o **Bitmap**:

```
File imagem = new File(pasta.getPath() + File.separator + "DiabetesMonitor_" + descricao + ".jpg");

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Agora é só adaptar p/ teu código, não consegui testar, mas acredito que esse é o caminho, espero que ajude.

Fontes: [Save images in an specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010739/android-save-images-in-an-specific-folder)
 - [file to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172154/convert-a-file-object-to-bitmap)